# Wrong input being focused

Tags: jquery

I have a html file with a bootstrap modal template; inside I got 2 `inputs` inside 2 separated `div's` with the only difference being: the first (`input`) has `countdown maxlength="140"` and the second doesn't.

I've created a function to focus the `input` everytime the `modal` is open:

```
// focus input every time modal is open
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.modal').on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
     $('.form-control').focus();
});
```

The problem is: the `input` being focused is the second (bottom) instead of the first.

Comment: Do they all have the same class? If so, that's your problem. If you want to target a specific one, put an `id` on it, and select by that

Comment: your html may have more than one element having class `.form-control`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan they do have the same class, but I would like to not use id's because I have multiple twigs with modals and that mean I'd have to create multiple id's as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you have multiple elements with the same `.form-control` class. jQuery then loops over all the elements it finds and triggers a `focus` event on them. As a result, only the last element found is left with the focus.

To fix this you can use `:first` to generically select the first input within the modal and only trigger `focus` on that:

```
$('.modal').on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
  $(this).find('.form-control:first').focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#modal-content').modal('show');
    $('#modal-content').on('shown', function () {
        $("#txtname").focus();
    })
});
```

try this one.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `$('.form-control').focus();` then this will focus last `input` if you want to focus first element then you should use

```
 $($('.form-control')[0]).focus();
```

If you don't want to this with index then you should `id` selector.

Comment: Or just `$('.form-control:first').focus()`